# How can i overwrite dir/help method on module?

Tags: python-2.7

```
>>> import module1
>>> dir(module1)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

I try putting some functions like this to module1 code:

```
def __dir__(self):
    return 'ok'
def __dir__():
    return 'ok'
def __dir__(self):
    print 'ok'
def __dir__():
    print 'ok'
```

... but nothing of those works. How good writen overwriting dir function should look?

I want something like this:

```
>>> import module1
>>> dir(module1)
'ok' [or ok]
```

Comment: Because `help(dir)` return '[...] If the object supplies a method named __dir__, it will be used; otherwise the default dir() logic is used and returns: [...]'.
About which function do you talking about? Write my own function to module1? Could you show me example?

Comment: I absolutely do not understand your actual use-case (and I deleted my previous comment because I misunderstood your intent). Can you please update your question to directly explain what you are trying to achieve? That way people can try and give you the right answer as opposed to guessing ways to solve your problem. I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish by doing a module-level dir()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is asking how to modify the behavior of `dir()` on module objects, but in your comments you clarified that your ultimate goal is to modify the behavior of `help(module)`. `dir` works differently on different objects, and I don't believe there is a direct way to change that for a module. It will simply always want to list the attributes of the module being everything in the scope.

What you can do though, is define an `__all__` attribute in your module, and specify which attributes should be made public in the help doc:

**mymodule**

```py
__all__ = ['foo']

foo = 'bar'

class Klass(object):
    pass

>>> import mymodule
>>> help(mymodule)
```

You will see that because `Klass` was excluded from `__all__` it will not be visible in the help.

Also, if you do `from mymodule import *`, only the foo attribute will be imported:

```py
>>> from mymodule import *
>>> dir()
# ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'foo']
```

Comment: I might recommend that you update your question/title to reflect wanting to modify the behavior of `help` so that people searching in the future will find your question.

Comment: Only attributes specified in `__all__` will be imporded in case of using `import *`. It is important. Thank You for answer and notification about specific behaviuor maked by `__all__`

Comment: Well ya thats to be expected. Both the `help` and `import *` deal with a public interface. There is nothing stopping you from doing `from mymodule import Klass` regardless of the `__all__` definition. It just requires the explicit import since its not considered a public attribute.